# Custom Metric data not showing up in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

**Background**

I am currently using Google Tag Manager to populate the Sales amount into a Custom Metric in Google Analytics. This is the code I use to push Sales amount to Google Analytics.

```
ga('set', 'metric2', {{salesvalue}});
```

**Other information**

- My custom metric set up in Google Analytics: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vZFr.png
- I know that the metric is firing with the correct values since it is showing up in GA Debugger: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2sFn.png

**Error**

Despite the above, I do not see any information in Google Analytics: https://i.stack.imgur.com/djdZn.png

**Questions**

1. Is there anything wrong with my setup? I have waited over 3 days but still no data.
2. By using ga('set') does it mean that if a user makes 2 separate purchases in the same session, only the latest sales figure will be reflected instead of the total of the 2 purchases?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your GA Debugger console, the `metric2` parameter should be appearing within the pageview send data (along with all the other data being sent to GA at that time). If it is not there, you could be running into a race condition or some other technical issue. If it *is* there, then you'll know that it is definitely being sent to Google Analytics and something else is wrong. It should not take long to appear, and if you see any rows of data (as you did with your screenshot) the metric data would be there at that time.

Regarding your 2nd question, custom *dimensions* have scopes that are configured when you create them, but custom metrics simply add up. If I had a custom metric of "clicks on a button" and user clicked it 3 times in their session, the custom metric would be 3. Likewise, if your custom metric is listening for sales value, it will add up to the total value in that session.

Hope that helps at least get you some more clues as to what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I found out the issue. It has got to do with this "If you don't record a dimension for a metric, then you cannot obtain the value of the metrics for which you didn't record a dimension by applying a filter on the dimension." [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7972978/google-analytics-exclude-empty-custom-variable-in-a-custom-report) Would you happen to know where I can reach up on all these minutiae? I spent days trying to troubleshoot this :(

Comment: Thanks for sharing your findings. Yeah, documentation on Google Analytics, while not bad, does leave out lots of nuances like that. You've probably already found some of the most notable links, but [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets) and [especially this](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828) are the best *official* documentation pages when it comes to that. However, per your example, they don't explicitly say things like what you ran into.